# Alchemy CMS - Cloudinary - Image crop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, crop, cloudinary, alchemy-cms

In Alchemy CMS how can I use the `Cloudinary` feature for get the image in the size that I want?

I need this for:

- a specific image, I mean that, one image could be 400x300 and another could be 200x200
- for all the images of the same element

How can I do it?

In the element definition, in `elements.yml`, I can use the settings property:

```
- name: content_block
  contents:
  - name: title_text
    type: EssenceText
    default: :title_text_sample
  - name: picture
    type: EssencePicture
    settings:
      size: 400x300
      crop: true
  - name: multi_line_text
    type: EssenceRichtext
```

but this is the same for all contents and I think that in this way the resize is done by the Alchemy server and not by the cloudinary.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to edit the URLs manually? If so you can change the size of the images on the fly. For example, http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200/sample

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but...
This is what I am asking...
I do not know how can I do it...